# Merge string differences with Access SQL/VBA

Tags: string, ms-access, merge

I have two Fields, with partly different strings. FieldA:= "String1" FieldB:= "String1; String2" (So, the main difference between the two fields is the "; String2" in FieldB). The result i want to see is also "String1; String2", but the first half i want from FieldA, and the second half i want from FieldB. Is there any way using Access SQL/VBA function to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use string manipulation functions. This is a relatively simple case for string manipulation, assuming the strings are consistent with the examples given. Consistency is critical to string manipulation. Assuming there is a space following the semi-colon, try:

`[FieldA] & "; " & Mid([FieldB], InStr([FieldB], ";") + 2)`

Expression can be used in query or textbox or VBA.

Suggest you do some research and learn about these and other string functions.

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that your values will *always* contain a semi-colon, you could also use the `Split` function in the following way:

```
[FieldA] & ";" & Split([FieldB],";")(1)
```

Comment: @June7 Sorry, I saw the request for VBA and thought of this alternative; you're correct in that `Split` is not accessible outside of VBA.